# prompt is not displayed with system.out in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, console

I have some issues with console user interaction.
The code below does not show the prompt. I'm running it with netbeans. Any idea?

```
    public class PromptTest {
      void prompt() {
        System.out.print("Enter something >>");
        System.out.flush();
      }

      void loop() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        prompt();
        System.out.flush();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
          System.out.println("Yout gave me : ["+sc.nextLine()+"]");
          prompt();
        }
      } 
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        PromptTest pt = new PromptTest();
        pt.loop();
      }
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: have you debugged your code and checked what that boolean condition in your if returns?

Comment: This code should definitely print something. Are you sure you are running this very class? Can you recompile it?